# workflow failed to get user profile SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I have a workflow which is unable to send an email to the users.
I got this in the log :

> "workflow failed to get user profile".

The user in the  "CC" field receives the email but the "TO" field doesn't.
The "TO" field  is a column of content type:

Alert recipient; this field type is "user or group"  I need to use Allow multiple users.
Note that if only one user allowed,the reception of the email is perfectly done.

Looking Up for String:

> FIELD DATA TO RETRIVE:Data Source:USER PROFILES,Return field as String
>   Find the list Item :Field:Account Name,Value:currentItem Alert
>   Receipeint. Looking Up for Person or Group: Data Source:current Item
>   Field from source:Alert Receipeint. Return Field As:Email Address.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check this blog post out, it should cover all the bases you need to use user or group field while sending email to all users contained in such field:

http://brainstorage.wordpress.com/2013/06/14/sending-workflow-emails-to-users-or-groups-from-a-person-or-group-field/

tl;dr: Need to get comma delimited Display or Login Names from the field :)